# 2 PyQT Interface in 1 Python file

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible to have 2 PyQT  UI in 1 .py file?

Example code:

```
Class a(object):
    *insert code for PyQT First UI
Class b(QMainWindow):
    *insert code for PyQT Second UI
```

Class a runs first, but how do i switch from Class a to Class b and vice versa?

Comment: Could you be more precise in you problem ? What dou you mean by "switch from Class a to Class b" ?

Comment: I am sorry, what i meant is to switch from Interface 1 to Interface 2. Class a and b has a different interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One file can contain as many ui classes as you want.  Just by declaring the class does not run the ui.  You can display the ui in several different ways.

To display a second QWidget from your class a, you can call it from a method like this:

```
def show_b(self):
    self.dialog = b()
    self.dialog.show()
```

This works if class b is a QWidget.  If it is a QDialog, it can be displayed as follows:

```
def show_b(self):
    dialog = b()
    dialog.show() # this line makes the dialog non-modal, it is optional
    dialog.exec_() # displays the dialog
```

Comment: sorry, but i'm new to python. Is QMainWindow a QWidget?

Comment: QMainWindow inherits from QWidget.  A QWidget class is a blank canvas to build on.  A QMainWindow has some extra features built in, like a menu bar, that are common to many applications.  [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) is the documentation for the QMainWindow class, and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) is the documentation for the QWidget class.  They explain in more detail.  They are in c++, but they provide a lot useful information and most parts can easily be translated to python even if you don't know c++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two windows and be able to switch to either one of them, you just have to declare them in your main file:

```
def main_Window_A(QMainWindow):
    # code for window A

def main_window_B(QMainWindow):
    # code for window B

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window_A = main_Window_A()
    window_A.show()

    window_B = main_Window_B()
    window_B.show()        

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```